# WPF or WinForms Media Player UI

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, media-player

Please advise any open-source .NET video player with a nice UI.

I'm actually looking for a player interface I can re-use in my own simple video playback application.

So far I only found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18552/C-Movie-Player). Any other good alternatives using WinForms or WPF?

All other .NET player interface designs I found were looking pretty poor. There are lots of PSD designs, but they are very difficult to convert to .NET.

Comment: Just a side note: there is c API for Winamp and there is .Net wrapper for this API.Here is the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wacc/?_test=b